# can i do encryption and make API secure in R

Tags: r, plumber

as I make a server with Plumber in R

it working properly

but now i want to do Three thing using it !

1> Encryption

2> Secure(https)

3> Compression

can i do this with plumber ?

If yes then please give me reference

Thanks

Comment: Please look up [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).